# How to prevent the scrolling of an image set as a QTextEdit background when the QTextEdit is scrolled, in PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to set the background of a QTextEdit to that of an image using `.setBrush(QPalette.Base, QBrush(QPixmap()))`

This works about fine, until the user inputs enough text on the QTextEdit to trigger the scroll-bar into appearing. Using the scroll-bar causes sections of the image to repeat. From what I assume, QT is trying to 'scroll' the image as well, and with no information about what exists past the image bounds, it just repeats portions of the image

Note, it does not TILE the image, it repeats rows of the image. Here are two images for reference, one of the QTextEdit pre-scrolling and the other of the QTextEdit post-scrolling

[image: pre-scrolliong]

[image]

Oddly enough, the repeated rows disappear and the image returns to normal if I were to minimize and reopen the window later, or if I hit the Windows Key button on my keyboard

I can't for the life of me figure out why it happens. I've tested it out with a bunch of different images. This image in particular happens to be causing problems.

The below is an example of a program which can be used to replicate this issue.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPalette, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit

app = QApplication([])
q = QMainWindow()

text = QTextEdit()
palette = text.palette()
palette.setBrush(QPalette.Base, QBrush(QPixmap('spacebg.png')))
text.setPalette(palette)
text.setFixedSize(QSize(1280,720))
q.setCentralWidget(text)
q.show()

app.exec()
```

Here is the image in particular:
[image]

Is there anyway to disable the scrolling of the background of a QTextEdit? Or is there any reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: I'd suggest you to set the background using [stylesheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qabstractscrollarea) instead of using the palette (which would also propagate to *all* child widgets).

Comment: @musicamante Really sorry. Forgot to mention in my post. I can't really be using stylesheets here for reasons I can't divulge at the moment. Is there a way to pull it off using the palette?

Comment: I would also like to add that I'd also wanted to know why this happened exactly. From what I saw in the docs, QBrush should just tile the image instead of repeating rows as seen in my example

Comment: That seems a bug, but I can't test your code right now; in the meantime I'd suggest you to try to set the palette for the viewport: `text.viewport().setPalette(palette)`.

Comment: @musicamante I've tried that, to no avail. Issue still occurs

Comment: The alternative is to subclass the QTextEdit, override `paintEvent` and draw the background *before* calling the base implementation. Note that you need to create the painter for the viewport: `painter = QPainter(self.viewport())`. I'd suggest you to cache the pixmap and rewrite it in the `resizeEvent()` override, in case you want it to scale to contents, and if you want it to scroll use the scroll bars values to translate the painter.

Comment: @musicamante I am assuming this problem has something to do with the paint event of the viewport/bg. Wouldn't overriding the paint event and then calling the base implementation bring up the problem again? I am also curious, how would I go about drawing the background? The last I dealt with paint events, I could only draw basic shapes and stuff?

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the painting of the background and update clipping, so don't set the palette, override `paintEvent()`, draw the pixmap with a QPainter created for the viewport, and *then* call `super().paintEvent(event)`; it's not 100% guaranteed that it will work, but it should. Anyway, I am not able to reproduce the problem on Linux, so it might be related to your plaftorm (some issue with buffering, maybe at graphics card driver level). What OS do you have? Does the problem still occur if you don't set the fixed size on the QTextEdit?

Comment: @musicamante I am on a Windows machine. Yes, the issue still happens if I don't set any particular fixed size. Also for the solution you've provided, would it be right for me to assume that the overrided paintevent draws the exact same pixmap everytime I scroll/paint event is called? So it looks the same regardless of how much you've scrolled?